# Mobilefirst Plaform handle client event

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I'm using mobilefirst platform 8.0 to develop my application, i'm handling back-end side, i have a question:

> a client got an event like some news update, and when client hit the
>   button it want another clients will be get notification about. How to
>   do it ?

can I use adapter to send events from a client to another clients ?

Answer (score 0):

No - you can't send push notifications directly from one mobile device to another...
I might recommend that you build it this way:

- Mobile user 1 calls an adapter function that updates or inserts a row to a database table in the backend;
- A server process detects that a new row has been inserted (maybe with a database trigger or some polling component), and calls the MFP server-side API to send a push notification for a specific tag;
- All the mobile clients that have subscribed to that tag will get the notification;

-Paul Horan-
IBM